# If you see me, I may be tied up

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

If you see me, I may be tied up.

And if you need me, you may want me around a pup.

If you're suicidal, I might be adorned.

And if I touch you, you might become burned.

I'm associated with licorice,

Yet just as often seen with fish.

What am I?

*The answer is one word.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer may be

> Rope

If you see me, I may be tied up.

> Rope is often tied up/around objects.

And you need me, you may want me around a pup.

> This may be a reference to [dog rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_rope) or the fact that some dog leashes are made from rope.

If you're suicidal, I might be adorned.

> Possible reference to a noose.

And if I touch you, you might become burned.

> [Rope Burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction_burn)

I'm associated with licorice,

> [Super Ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Ropes)

Yet just as often seen with fish.

> Fishing nets are often knitted with rope. This is also perhaps a reference to a [rope fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reedfish)